# MySql, loop (while foreach)

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, while-loop

I have a big problem. I get data from a database. I want to display them in tabs. My method is a loop in a loop. I show you the code. My problem is that the result (second loop) all data are output.

The first loop displays each user name with the same id, in a own tab. that works. the second loop operates on the same principle. but the second loop does not filter.

(!)
**The first loop show me correctly for every username with the same id the own Tab. but the sec on loop show me all event_names, not only the event names of the users.
Resume: i got 3 user. every user. user 1 has his own tab. (2 events) user 2 has his own tab. (1 event) user 3 has his own tab. (1 event) in the second loop, i ask the events of every user. in the tab of user 1 must appear 2 events in the tab of user 2 must appear 1 event and in the tab of user 3 must appear 1 event too. BUT, in every tab (user 1,2 and 3) appear 4 events. the events of all users... is it a problem with the loop, isn't it?**
(!)

Can someone help me?

Here some pictures of the table and output:

My table users

[image]

the code:

```
<?php    
$db = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_BENUTZER, DB_password, DB_NAME);
mysqli_set_charset($db, "utf8");
$sqli2 = "SELECT username, premium FROM users WHERE id =  $id   ";  
$result2 = mysqli_query($db, $sqli2);   
foreach ($result2 as $row2)     
        {   
           echo '<div class="tabs">';
```

My table party:

[image]

the code:

```
$db = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_BENUTZER, DB_password, DB_NAME);
mysqli_set_charset($db, "utf8");
$sqli = "SELECT party_id, event_name, beginn, ende, unternehmen FROM party WHERE unternehmen =  '".$row2['username']."'   ";  
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sqli);    
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    echo '<h3> '. $row['unternehmen'] .' '. $row['event_name'] .' </h3>';
```

and my output:
[image]

Where is the error? I can't believe it :-( Please help me!!!!

here the full code:

```
<?php


$db = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_BENUTZER, DB_password, DB_NAME);
mysqli_set_charset($db, "utf8");
$sqli2 = "SELECT username, premium FROM users WHERE id =  $id   ";  
$result2 = mysqli_query($db, $sqli2);


 foreach ($result2 as $row2) {


           echo '<div class="tabs">';
  echo '<ul>';
  echo '<li><a href="#tabs-1"> '. $row2['username'] .' </a></li>';
  echo '<li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>';
  echo '<li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>';
  echo '</ul>';
  echo '<div id="tabs-1">';
  echo '<p>Proin elit ac sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam us.</p>';






  echo '</div>';
  echo '<div id="tabs-2">';




   echo '<p><div class="accordion">';


$db = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_BENUTZER, DB_password, DB_NAME);
mysqli_set_charset($db, "utf8");
$sqli = "SELECT party_id, event_name, beginn, ende, unternehmen FROM party WHERE unternehmen =  '".$row2['username']."'   ";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sqli);


    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
        {        


    echo '<h3> '. $row['unternehmen'] .' '. $row['event_name'] .' </h3>'; 
    echo '<div> ';
    echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" >';
    echo '<legend>Event Daten</legend>';
    echo '<label for="event_name">Name:</label>';
    echo '<input type="text" id="event_name" name="event_name" value="'. $row['event_name'] .'" /><br />';
    echo '<label for="beginn">Beginn:</label>';
    echo '<input type="text" id="beginn" name="beginn" value=" '. $row['beginn'] .'" /><br />';
      echo '<label for="party_id" value=" '. $row['party_id'].'"> Party ID:'. $row['party_id'].' </label>';
      echo '<input type="radio" id="party_id" name="party_id" value=" '. $row['party_id'] .'" /><br />';

  echo '</fieldset>';
  echo '<input type="submit" value="Änderungen speichern" name="partyspeicher" />';
  echo '</form>';
        echo '</div>';

         }

    echo '</div>';
    echo '</p>';


    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div id="tabs-3">';
    echo '<p> Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>';
  echo '</div>';
  echo '</div>';
   }      





?>
```

Comment: Might be best to post the whole code.

Comment: Hello, before your $sqli, do $user = $row2['username']; , and in your $sqli variable replace $row[username] with $user and see if that changes anything. Why this? Well $row2[username] won't work since it should be $row2['username'] ... and to avoid the whole quotations problems, just create an extra variable.

Comment: no it doesn't change. i got 3 user. every user.
user 1 has his own tab. (2 events)
user 2 has his own tab. (1 event)
user 3 has his own tab. (1 event)
in the second loop, i ask the events of every user. 
in the tab of user 1 must appear 2 events
in the tab of user 2 must appear 1 event and
in the tab of user 3 must appear 1 event too.
BUT,
in every tab (user 1,2 and 3) appear 4 events. the events of all users...
it it a problem with the loop, isn't it?

Comment: @Philip the whole code is posted now. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 2):

I'll just post this as an answer instead of a comment.

It seems your problem is directly related with your sql string:

```
$sqli = "SELECT party_id, event_name, beginn, ende, unternehmen FROM party WHERE unternehmen =  '$row2[username]'   ";
```

Notice your `$row2[username]` , it should be `$row2['username']` but this may cause a problem in your sql string. Create another variable called `$username`

```
$username = $row2['username'];
$sqli = "SELECT party_id, event_name, beginn, ende, unternehmen FROM party WHERE unternehmen =  '$username'   ";
```

And see if that changes anything.

**For future reference:**

I would recommend using PDO (more secure) instead of mysqli. Relatively easy to use with a lot of useful functionalities, such as *bindValue()* function, which would replace `$username = $row2['username'];` with something like

```
 $sqli = $db->prepare("SELECT party_id, event_name, beginn, ende, unternehmen FROM party WHERE unternehmen =  ':user'   ");
$sqli->blindValue(':user', $row2['username'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

(if $db was a PDO object)
http://php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.bindvalue.php

Comment: No its not this the problem. the problem is, that the first loop show all username, and in the second loop it make it too...

Comment: no it doesn't change. i got 3 user. every user.
user 1 has his own tab. (2 events)
user 2 has his own tab. (1 event)
user 3 has his own tab. (1 event)
in the second loop, i ask the events of every user. 
in the tab of user 1 must appear 2 events
in the tab of user 2 must appear 1 event and
in the tab of user 3 must appear 1 event too.
BUT,
in every tab (user 1,2 and 3) appear 4 events. the events of all users...
it it a problem with the loop, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

your second query should be this

```
    $sqli = "SELECT party_id, event_name, beginn, ende, unternehmen 
FROM party WHERE unternehmen =  '".$row2['username']."'   "
```

you are missing single quete in username means it should be $row['username'];

always turn on the error or use `mysqli_error()` function they will tell what wrong.

Please check this link to sharp your knowlede **http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html**

Comment: no it doesn't change. i got 3 user. every user.
user 1 has his own tab. (2 events)
user 2 has his own tab. (1 event)
user 3 has his own tab. (1 event)
in the second loop, i ask the events of every user. 
in the tab of user 1 must appear 2 events
in the tab of user 2 must appear 1 event and
in the tab of user 3 must appear 1 event too.
BUT,
in every tab (user 1,2 and 3) appear 4 events. the events of all users...
it it a problem with the loop, isn't it?

Comment: now i have updated my question :-) i hope now its clear. Sorry my bad english :-S